# Can we forward the answers from my bad question to my good question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

Can we forward the answers from my bad question to my good question?

My bad question: [Repertoire recommendation for beginning viola?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9458/repertoire-recommendation-for-beginning-viola)

My good question: [What to look for in beginner etudes for a second instrument?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9493/what-to-look-for-in-beginner-etudes-for-a-second-instrument)

The answers to the bad question are no worse for the change of venue, I think. But when the bad one gets closed, *that* will tend to shadow over these fine contributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two simple solutions here

- the easiest is to request the two questions be merged, that will bring the old questions over
- alternatively ask the posters to repost them

Having had a look at the questions and answers, I think a merge will not be confusing - all answers will fit on the good question.

Comment: Done!​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewRead!